# How to setup index for virtual table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, query-optimization

Currently, I have an module for virtual table in SQLite to import data from hard disk. Well, the data on disk are sorted already, how can I setup the bestindex in the module to use b-tree or the external index? is there any sample? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "b-tree" or "external index"? Any indexes returned by `bestIndex` must be implemented by you.

Comment: If I have an index file also exist on harddisk, Could I use it in my virtual table? And How to write an index, do you have some example? thanks.

Comment: There are samples (e.g., FTS) in the SQLite source code.